# Putting JavaScript external file to Xampp

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, xampp

I try to put an external JavaScript file which is fully written in jQuery and save as .js file to Xampp and I tried everything and it is not working. Xampp does not read .js file at all . What should I do? Can anyone help? I read most articles on internet and all were irrelevant.I tried to copy and paste JavaScript file inside HTML codes but still it does not work either.also I restarted Xampp several times,changed the local file address on html JavaScript file ,cleared cache , restarted computer etc. and none of them worked.

Comment: Can you please add more info about your problem? Are there any errors in the console? Please edit the questions with further info and even the js code you are trying to implement

Comment: I am not sure what type of info you need ! I have simply one HTML file, one CSS file and one .Js file related to a responsive navigation menu .I never checked console.JavaScript code function is too make it a toggle menu adaptable to mobile phones.

Comment: maybe it's not from xampp, change your browser and see if it's the same

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you could include: a) The script tag you use in your HTML page and b) The folder structure of your app. (including the location of your index.html and the javascript file)

Comment: I changed and checked on all browsers and result was the same.

Comment: if you don't share your code how it is suppossed that someone can help you?

Comment: ParaD , about tag , I use general JavaScript tag :

<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
<script src='script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
and I placed them inside <head> tag in HTML. And folder path is on htdocs . I mean all files are there ,index.html,.css and .js files are there.

Comment: It seems like your tag is not right. First try to add "HTTP://" as prefix (HTTP://ajax...), Second, where is the script.js located? it might not be called at all. Please click F12 and check if there are errors

PS: Please edit your main question add code block and paste to it your HTML file

Comment: As @AlonAlbahari mentioned, try prepending "https:" (or "http:") to your jQuery plugin script tag URL. And also try prepending forward slash (/) to the script file name. Like: 
<script src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='/script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
Also make sure your filenames are correct (make sure no typos)

Comment: All tags for js and css should point to path on htdocs where all files are located , correct?

Comment: Apparently my `https://` part is removed from my comment. But make sure it's there at the beginning of your jQuery plugin URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. Change the `<script src='ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'>` to `<script src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'>`, then place your own `js` tag just before the closing of your `body` tag instead on `head` tag, just like this:

`<script src='script.js' type="text/javascript"></script></body>`

The way web pages are loaded it may be possible that the references inside your `js` are not yet loaded when the browser reaches your js on the `head` tag. If you place it at the bottom then when the browser reaches your `js` it can be executed because every reference was already loaded.

Notice that the declaration of the type kind `type="text/javascript"`is no longer required so you can remove it.

Comment: Thank you . I am out at work . When I get home , I will do and post the result.so all my .css and .js tags should have path to htdocs or is it necessary?

Comment: If you simply create a `my-project` folder inside htdocs and place there all your code it's enough when you request `localhost:your-port/my-project`

Comment: Thanks. Which port should I request? Port 80?can you tell me how should it look like?” , I mean localhost request? I normally just type localhost and it goes to root.

Comment: Then jus localhost as the port depends on the server configuration. If you normally use localhost, then just `localhost/my-project`

Comment: I changed whole structure of codes . It works for now

Comment: Well if the answer helped you then consider up voting and selecting as the accepted answer. Thanks.